# Why am I getting a parse error on input '=' Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am getting a parse error on input '=' when trying to run the following code

```
module GiveNums
  where
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  n <- giveNum
  sum = map (+) n
  putStrLn "The sum is " ++ show sum

giveNum = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  putStrLn "Enter num"
  num <- getLine
  if read num == 0
    then return []
  else do
   rest <- giveNum
   return ((read num :: Int: rest)
```

Comment: In short: Because that isn't legal Haskell syntax.  Longer: binding variables is `let var = expr`.  Also: `map (+) n` won't give a single number but a list of functions, you probably want fold. Also: `f x :: ty : xs` won't parse right you need parens such as `(f x :: ty) : xs)`.

Comment: Also `sum` is already taken as a variable name, it's the name of a function.  Do a `:t sum` and a `:i sum` in ghci, or search it.    I'd suggest that you comment out your `main` function for now and get your `giveNum` function working.  It's really close to working, especially with Thomas' last suggestion.  Then, once `giveNum` works, start on `main`.

Comment: Like, really close. Like, one character away from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: **because your code has syntax error.**

Some additional comments:

1. You don't need `module` when working with a single code file. `module` is for writing a library.
2. Bindings in `main :: IO ()` need `let` because it is in the `IO Monad`. Read more about `do` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)
3. Setting `stdin` buffering mode only once is enough.
4. There is a [sum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sum) function in Prelude.

I tried to make the code as close to the original as possible. However, this is not good Haskell code.

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  n <- giveNum
  let summation = sum n
  putStrLn $ "The sum is " ++ show summation

giveNum :: IO [Int]
giveNum = do
  putStrLn "Enter num"
  num <- read <$> getLine

  if num == 0
    then return []
    else do
         rest <- giveNum
         return $ num: rest
```

Output:

```
$ runhaskell givenum.hs 
Enter num
1
Enter num
2
Enter num
3
Enter num
0
The sum is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if you want to "assign" something in a do statement you need to put `let` before it, so `sum = map (+) n` turns into `let sum = map (+) n`, but as wizzup pointed out sum is already defined as a standard function and also `let sum = map (+) n` wont return the sum of integers in `n` , for that you would need [`foldr`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/foldr_f.html)

`let sumOfn = foldr (+) 0 n`

But it would be easier to do `let sumOfn = sum n`
Also, `let f =map (+) n` creates a list of functions of type `Int->Int`, if n is [1,2,3] then f is [(+1),(+2),(+3)].